# I am trying to fetch post data from mysql database. But the loop is running forever. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch post data from MySQL database. I have used while loop for fetching rows from the table. I have five rows in my MySQL database. But it is fetching rows until my browser crashes. Why is it happening? How to solve this problem?

This is the main code:

```
<div class="container clearFix">

    <?php
        while ($result = Data::fetch_table('posts')) {
    ?>

    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-title">
            <h2><?php echo $result['title'];?></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="date">
            Published on: <?php echo $result['post_date'];?>
        </div>

        <div class="post-body">
            <?php echo $result['body'];?>
        </div>

        <div class="read-more">
            <a href="sh07/post.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is the **Data Class** code:

class Data {

```
public static function fetch_table($table_name) {
    // Connection variables
    $con = new Database;
    $con = $con->connection();

    // SQL Queries
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Note: The database connection is already established in **Data Class**.

Thanks for your any help.

Comment: You can `fetch_assoc` in a while in the `fetch_table` function and just return the results and `foreach` them.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `fetch_table` you connect to the database, make a query, and return the first result.

Your while loop keeps going until it doesn't get a result … which will never happen because you always start from a new connection and give it the first result.

You need to connect to the database **once**, make the query **once**, and then repeatedly call **only** `fetch_assoc` until you run out of rows.

Comment: Thanks. Well explained.